# LINQ query over generic list of user types

Tags: c#, linq

I wish to search to see if a string called `tempName` is already contained in a List of user objects. These user objects of type `userClass` contain a string data method `Name` whose value i'd like to check against `tempName`.

How is this done in LINQ?

thanks

Using traditional for loops i can do it like this:

```
bool already = false;
for (int i = 0; i < userList.Count; i++)
{
    if (Name == userList[i].name) 
        already = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx), which uses an [expression lambda](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) (the bit with `user =>`) to specify the function used to test each user, and returns a boolean value:

```
string name = "the name you're searching for";
bool already = userList.Any(user => user.Name.Contains(name));
```

This has the (performance) advantage that it doesn't enumerate over all elements; it bails out once it finds the first element that satisfies the condition you specify.

Comment: @gwizardry: its a variable created at runtime which will hold this value `userList[i]` as if you were using in traditional for loops.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `users` contains the full list of users and `tempName` contains the name you want to filter on, this will do it:

```
var newUsers = users.Where(user => user.Name.Contains(tempName)).ToList()
```

Comment: @gwizardry: its a variable created at runtime which will hold this value `userList[i]` as if you were using in traditional for loops.

Comment: does it require traditional get/set definitions? (It seems to in my implementation)

Comment: no that lambda operator( => )does that. For each iteration it takes user[i] and puts it in user.

Comment: Serves me right for answering early while the question was still asking for the list of users, not for whether any matching the predicate exist.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing you edit of using traditional for loops you can use Any Extension Method of LINQ.

```
bool already = userList.Where(x => Name == x.Name).Any();
```

or

```
bool already = userList.Any(x => Name == x.Name);
```

Comment: `Any` has an overload which takes a predicate, which has a slightly better performance in both runtime and memory than the `.Where(predicate).Any()` solution.

Comment: @Nuffin: Is this(Second Snippet) what you were talking about?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, yes.

Comment: You should avoid using the `.Where(...).Any()` approach as the `Where` will enumerate over the entire collection (which is unnecessary), whereas `.Any(...)` bails out as soon as it finds a match.

Comment: @RichardEv: `.Where(...).Any()` does not iterate over the entire list, because LINQ uses deferred execution and the whole query is disposed once the first matching item is found. It is, however, slightly less efficient than the `.Any(...)` due to the additional iterator object.

Comment: @Nuffin: is LINQ smart enough to know to stop enumerating the `.Where` once the `.Any` is satisfied? I thought that each would be executed in turn.

Comment: @RichardEv: yeah, it is, as LINQ uses deferred execution (which comes almost for free with iterator blocks). Once `Any` finds a match, it disposes the `Where` iterator, which in turn disposes the iterator it iterates over and so on. Without that behavior, LINQ would be totally unusable, as it's speed and memory consumption would be horrible (List of n elements with m filters? Runtime and memory usage would be O(n * m), while it's actually only O(n + m), which is way better)